# PHP session problem with if statement

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I have the follow code:

```
function get_error(){
  $update = "";
  if($_SESSION['sessionName'][0] === 1){            
      $update .= "<div class='good'>You have just driven " . convertMiles($_SESSION['sessionName'][1], $this->units) . ".</div>";
      $_SESSION['sessionName'][0] = 0;
  }
  return $update;
}
```

With this the if statement fails, and get_error returns "" its like its setting the $_SESSION['sessionName'][0] to 0 and then running the if statement.

This does work:

```
function get_error(){
  $update = "";
  if($_SESSION['sessionName'][0] === 1){            
      $update .= "<div class='good'>You have just driven " . convertMiles($_SESSION['sessionName'][1], $this->units) . ".</div>";
      //$_SESSION['sessionName'][0] = 0;
  }
  return $update;
}
```

Why is it that comment out the session update inside of an if block (That shouldn't even be run until the condition is met and $update has been set).  ON this one get_error returns the html and works fine.

I really can't get this figured out and any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Also I set the session before this function gets called like this:

```
$_SESSION['sessionName'] = array(1,10);
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing out `$_SESSION['routeAmount'][0]` right before the if statement to confirm that it is 1?

Comment: It works when I comment out `$_SESSION['sessionName'][0] = 0;` it echos 1.  When I uncomment that even before the if block it is setting it to 0.  This is what is really confusing me...its running that session update before doing the if statement :/

Comment: Have you tried it with unset?

Comment: same thing as setting it to 0 (tried this before I came here).

Comment: Could `get_error()` be called more than once, maybe somewhere earlier in the script? Try putting `$_SESSION['sessionName'] = array(1,10);` in `get_error()` just for testing purposes.

Comment: setting it before the if statement worked, but when I did a search to see if it was getting called twice it only returned 2 results.  When function get_errors() is created (in the class file) and once in the main file when it gets called.  It is not used anywhere else.  I also did a search for sessionName to make sure it wasn't getting called anywhere else and it is only used in 2 places.  Once when it is set and another time with this if statement.  No where else is it being used :/

Comment: What's happening in convertMiles? And did you checked $this->units?

Comment: convertMiles is just a function I have to convert MPH to kMPH, $this->units is fine.  Like I said the if statement works exactly how its supposed to (include the convertMiles function) when I don't change its value.  The reason I want to change the value is that I want this message to only show once.  So if `$_SESSION['sessionName'][0] === 1` then I know it hasn't been shown, once I set it to 0 I know it has.  `$_SESSION['sessionName'][1]` just contains the speed they went so I can convert it if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
get_error($_SESSION['sessionName'][0]);

function get_error(&$whatever){
  $update = "";
  if($whatever === 1){            
      $update .= "<div class='good'>You have just driven " . convertMiles($_SESSION['sessionName'][1], $this->units) . ".</div>";
      $whatever = 0;
  }
  return $update;
}
```

HTH

Comment: problem with that is that I have other if statements in there that get called but they are all working fine :/  They all build on top of $update.  Its made so I only have to call it once.

Comment: Yeah I went to an IRC channel for PHP and they saw nothing wrong.  I'm really just lost at this point and am going to think of another way to do it.